# Format a string from my Database so there would be spaces

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, for the tittle it's a little hard to explain, so here:
I'm trying to `echo` text from my database.

First I'm getting my infos out of the Database:

```
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM docs");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $text = html_decode_entity($row['content']);
}
```

PS: The `$db_host`, `$db_user`, `$db_pass` are defined.

If the text have skipped lines(when you hit tab) and I echo them with a simple `echo` 
Like this:

```
echo "$text";
```

The text will only come with a single line.

Question: How can I display skipped lines?

I know the question is not well explained but yeah!

Comment: Every time you overwrite your `$text` variable within the `while` loop & what do mean by skipped lines? let us know.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Do you mean something like [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)?

Comment: @MrHappy,That's because browsers render multiple spaces as a single space. You need to use a string replace instruction on the data to change each space into a &nbsp; or use kind of `nl2br()` .see here http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Don’t use the `mysql_*` functions, they’re deprecated and will be removed in a future version of PHP.

Comment: @MartinBean What should I use then ?

Comment: @MrHappy As per http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php: “Instead, either the [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.”

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop, you are not appending the data to your `$text` variable!

You could do something like this:

```
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM docs");
$text = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $text .= html_decode_entity($row['content']) . "<br />";
}
```

Please note that, I have used `.=`. Which, has the same meaning like:

```
$text = $text . html_decode_entity($row['content']) . "<br />";
```

Another suggestion I have to make is, when you echo the variable's contents, you don't have to enclose the variable in double quotes. You could simply do like this:

```
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, and judging by your codes. You want to display all the results of the query and not just one.

`$text = html_decode_entity($row['content']);` will cause you to only have the last result assign to `$text` variable.

You can declare `$text = array();` before the loop. And put the results into the array like this `$text[] = html_decode_entity($row['content']);`. And display it like this:

```
foreach($text as $line){
    echo $line."\r\n";
}
```

OR you can declare the `$text = ''` before the loop. And in the loop concatenate the results like `$text .= html_decode_entity($row['content'])."\r\n";` and echo it like you did.

Comment: This is the best answer as it covers the most possibilites. Missing only the option to  $text = implode("\r\n",  $text) in place of the foreach. But that's PHP so many ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer was to use `nl2br()` apparently it's replacing the spaces with `"\r\n"` If I understand correctly...

Comment: nice nick & avatar match